# My app changes the local language programatically, but Notifications show their message in the device language

Tags: android, push-notification, localization, android-notifications

i can change my app's language programatically , but NotificationCompat keeps device language.
it's a local self notification ( not coming from Firebase ).

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String id = "id_notif";
        String name = "test_notif";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                mChannel.enableLights(true);
                mChannel.setShowBadge(true);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
        }



        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_revue)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                .setBadgeIconType(BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.title)).setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.content));
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(magazine.getFilePath().hashCode(), notification);
```

iam using a Service class to donwnload files , at the end of the download i show the notification.

```
class MagazineDownloadService extends WakefulIntentService
```

what can be wrong ?

Comment: You need to change the language at the backend as well. It works separately from the front end.

Comment: How in the backend ?

Comment: While sending data, send the language parameter key let's suppose "Arabic", and write the same messages code in Arabic just like the Android. So when you send the key to backend, it will send you the Arabic language message.

Comment: I am not sending data from gcm or firebase , it’s a local notification (notification when a download is completed).so I still don’t understand your solution.

Comment: Ok, I thought you are managing it from backend. If you are managing it from front end, that is it is local then change the data into the corresponding language while you are setting the message of notification.

Comment: I did it but it’s not working

Comment: Might be you are missing something because it is completely depends on calling the method and its data message.